# sxhkd not working with XF keys (bspwm) (Thinkpad X220) (Debian 11)

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, thinkpad

All of my keys work wonderfully in sxhkd except for the XF keys such as `XF86MonBrightnessDown` , Up, and the XF keys for the increasing and decreasing sound.

Over [here](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) one can see in the example

```
{_,shift + ,super + }XF86MonBrightness{Down,Up}
bright {-1,-10,min,+1,+10,max}
```

being used, but when I simply copy it to my config it does nothing - no output and no change in brightness. This is also the same for the volume controls. I also tried replacing `bright` with `xbacklight` but to no avail.

The only other sort of relevant post was [on the BBS Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155613&p=2) where they suggested removing the XF prefix and it worked for that user, however not for me.

I tried asking `#linux` on IRC but I guess I picked the wrong time, nobody helped.

The last bit of relevant information was found just now on [the issue page for sxhkd](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd/issues/243). TL;DR for that one is that the same keys work and don't work depending on the laptop - for example, that user's T440 had no issues while on the T430 they only worked only partially even though the names for the keys were identical.

Just in case it might be relevant, the `uname -a` of my device :

```
Linux dxb 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[Here](http://termbin.com/x8sg)'s a `cat` of my `sxhkdrc` :

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I got one suggestion for you: Did you indent the bash command line of the keybinding statement?

It should look something like that:

```
{_,shift + ,super + }XF86MonBrightness{Down,Up}
    bright {-1,-10,min,+1,+10,max}
```

(First line starting at the beginning of the line and the second line starting some spaces after the beginning of it.)

I hope, this helped.

Comment: Thanks for answering . I did indeed to that but still no results.  Here's a cat of my sxhkdrc :

 https://termbin.com/x8sg

As you will see when you scroll down, I also tried multiple combinations and none of them worked, either alone or with possibly multiple conflicting ones as seen in my sxhkdrc file.

What's really annoying is that I just started using bspwm and found it an ideal wm for me, and this is literally the only complaint I have with it. Luckily I have polybar with it's brightness and audio controls so at least I can control those in some way.

Comment: Alright, sorry for that. That's all I could think of. Good luck finding the answer!

Comment: No problem, thank you for trying to help !